# Count rows notification

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a notification where the user will login and see how many pending requests do they still have when they login to the homepage. However, i am getting this error where it says count parameter must be array or object

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

What did I do wrong and how should i go about fixing it? Thanks.

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT status,request 
                         FROM orders 
                         WHERE status = 'Pending'
                         OR request = 'Pending'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if(!$result) die($conn->error);
                $rows = $result->num_rows;

                if (COUNT($rows['status']) OR COUNT($rows['request']) > 0) { 
                    echo "You have ".(COUNT($rows['status']) + COUNT($rows['request']))."pending notificatins.";
                }else{
                    echo "You have 0 pending notifications.";
                }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are passing the number of `$rows` into your `count` function where `count()` accept objects and arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you might be able to accomplish your goal like this where you assign each count within the sql and then, importantly, fetch the recordset to begin processing.

```
<?php
    $sql = 'select
                ( select count(*) from `orders` where `status`='pending' ) as `status-count`,
                ( select count(*) from `orders` where `request`='pending' ) as `request-count`'; 

    $result = $conn->query( $sql );
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    if( $result && $rows > 0 ){
        $rs = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        $status=$rs[0]['status-count'];
        $request=$rs[0]['request-count'];

        if( $status > 0 or $request > 0 ){
            printf('You have %s pending notifications: [ Status=%d, Request=%d ]', ( $status + $request ), $status, $request );
        }else{
            echo 'You have 0 pending notifications.';
        }
    }
?>
```

It is true that for the PHP logic in the question a simplified query, such as that shown by @marcin orlowski below will give the correct count and allow the logic to work it does not allow you to determine, should you wish, what number of `status` or `requests` there are

Comment: would the downvoter care to illuminate me as to why the negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

No point fetching all the rows just to count them. You need different query:

```
SELECT COUNT(request) 
           FROM orders 
            WHERE status = 'Pending'
            OR request = 'Pending'
```

Comment: since i need to count both status and request, should my query be like SELECT COUNT(status, request)...?

Comment: No this is invalid syntax, but even so no need to do that . You are counting rows matching your WHERE and each row has both status and request, so count is the same

Comment: use `count(*)` and you get the sum of `status = 'Pending' OR request = 'Pending'`

Comment: I'm actually trying to count both request and status and summing them up together cuz they are under different columns, hence if 1 status record is pending and 2 request record is pending, i want it to echo out as 3 notifications

Comment: My query counts ALL rows matching your WHERE clause. And since you got OR there it is sufficient to just one of these fileds in the given row be `Pending`  for the row to be accounted. Try it